# Swift Notifications Action

Tags: swift, push-notification, notifications, push

I'm trying to add "actions" for the notifications like the below screenshot. It's simply a question and based on user tap action, either question is not asked again for a certain time or changes to be done in Settings to disable notifications.
I tried to search for a code sample, but could not find any.

[image: Text]

Comment: Hi @MohamedElBasyouni, please search more before ask question and wirte more explanation about your question. However I found some details about your question -> https://makeapppie.com/2017/01/09/actions-in-push-notifications/

Comment: @EmreCiftci, I have already done and found nothing. I believe it's not the regular action like the one you already shared as I can see the same question with the same "actions" and the same behavior through multiple apps from different developers. I'm aware, even if I didn't implement, the regular notifications actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very long search with different keywords, I came to know that this is a feature that was first introduced in iOS 12 as Provisional Authorization for Quiet Notifications.
I found a source code on github [here](https://github.com/iosbrain/iOS-12-Provisional-Authorization-for-Quiet-Notifications) that can be investigated further. Another tutorial can also be found [here](http://iosbrain.com/blog/2018/07/05/new-in-ios-12-implementing-provisional-authorization-for-quiet-notifications-in-swift/).